# Custom bottom navigation bar layout

Tags: android, android-layout, android-xml, android-bottomnav

I want to create the following customized `BottomNavigationBar`. How can I set custom layout for the same?

[image]

Can somebody tell me how to approach it ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can check this library, hope this helps! [BottomNavigationCircles-Android](https://github.com/Kwasow/BottomNavigationCircles-Android)

Answer (score 0):

If you are OK with using Material components, this article should be of use: https://protocoderspoint.com/custom-bottom-navigation-bar-android/.

This is a relatively easy thing to find on Google, so I advise looking there for some help.

Check out sites like https://github.com/roughike/BottomBar if you want to build upon a pre-built layout/system.

As far as I can tell though, there is no method to set android:layout="@layout/mylayout" function for bottom nav bars.

Search GitHub for "custom bottom navigation bar" and try to build off of the dirty work that has been done there. It will save a lot of time and headache while you're trying to build the back-end navigation patterns and layout inflators.